# Google Sheets - IF cell contains certain text (or texts) then return values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've been searching all over and can't get this right. I am trying to create an alert that returns a word or words when certain words are found in a cell. I want the formula to search for specific words in the same cell and when it gets a match it will return a certain value/values.

For example, the formula will look for any of the next words in the cell F10 and then return the correspondent text if found. In case there are two or more matches it will return several answers.

- Found "Pizza" or "Hotdog" in F10? - **Return** "Food"
- Found "Apple" or "Banana" in F10? - **Return** "Fruit"
- Found "Coffee" or "Coke" in F10? - **Return** "Drink"
- Found "Pizza" AND "Apple" - **Return** "Food" AND "Fruit"
- Found "Pizza" AND "Apple" AND "Coke" - **Return** "Food" AND "Fruit" AND "Drink".

Appreciate all help!

Comment: Be more specific about what words. Is there a list of words somewhere? What about false positives e.g. 'Apples' contains 'Apple' but is a different word. Does it have to be case-sensitive? Do you want to return a list or concatenated values....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Concatenated values

```js
=join(", ",query({if(or(REGEXMATCH( upper($F$10),"PIZZA"), REGEXMATCH( upper($F$10),"HOTDOG")),"FOOD",);if(or(REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"APPLE"),REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"BANANA")),"FRUIT",);if(or(REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"COFFEE"),REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"COKE")),"DRINK")}, "select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image: ex1]

---

##### List Values

```js
=query({if(or(REGEXMATCH( upper($F$10),"PIZZA"), REGEXMATCH( upper($F$10),"HOTDOG")),"FOOD",);if(or(REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"APPLE"),REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"BANANA")),"FRUIT",);if(or(REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"COFFEE"),REGEXMATCH(upper($F$10),"COKE")),"DRINK")}, "select * where Col1 is not null")
```

[image: ex2]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. You have no idea how thankful I am!

Comment: What if instead of returning food or drink or fruit I wanted it to return the value that it's on another cell (hyperlink text). Like if it finds Pizza it will return the hyperlink text that its on cell B11. Tried switching the text with the cell but it wont return the hyperlink but plain text. Thank you!

Comment: @coffee709 i believe you would need to use the `HYPERLINK` formula to turn it into an actual link. for example, `…, HYPERLINK(B1, “Link”),…`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B10, ", "), SPLIT({
 {"Pizza"; "Hotdog"}&"×Food"; 
 {"Apple"; "Banana"}&"×Fruit"; 
 {"Coffee"; "Coke"}&"×Drink"}, "×"), 2, 0))))
```

[image]